# normalize the volume level of an mp3 file with sox using maximum bitrate for the new file

Tags: audio, mp3, sox

I have lots of mp3 files that were set (by some buggy tool) to such a low gain level, that there is nothing to hear any more.

This command

```
for f in *.mp3; do sox --norm "$f" /tmp/sox.mp3; mv -v /tmp/sox.mp3 "$f";
```

resets the volume of all files in the current folder to a normal level, but `sox` uncompresses and re-compresses lossy formats while processing, so iterated compression will cause slight detoriation of quality.

How do I minimize the additional detoriation while re-encoding? I would use mp3 with a bitrate of 320 for the output file, but I could not find any hint for this in the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/sox.1.html)

Comment: This question has some more answers on https://askubuntu.com/a/1286137/34298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoudGain seems to be the perfect tool:
https://github.com/Moonbase59/loudgain

> It uses the well-known mp3gain commandline syntax but will never modify the actual audio data.
> Just what you ever wanted: The best of mp3gain, ReplayGain 2.0 and Linux combined.

It reduces gain to -1 dBTP  (instead of 0 dBTP, according to EBU recommendation).  Almost a security margin in the event that the further playout route "only" understands ReplayGain, but has no clipping prevention

#### Install LoudGain (using Homebrew):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh
# first check what you get before install ;)
less install.sh
# press q and then install homebrew with:
/bin/bash -c install.sh
brew install Moonbase59/tap/loudgain
```

recommended use for mp3:

```
loudgain -I3 -S -L -a -k -s e *.mp3
```

see https://github.com/Moonbase59/loudgain/blob/master/docs/loudgain.1.md#recommendations

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [mp3gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3Gain), which will (reversibly) change the scale factor in each MP3 frame to adjust the volume. Modifying an MP3 file in this way doesn't require uncompression and recompression; the sound will be just as good (or bad) as the original.

However, be aware that if the source MP3s you have are low quality due to the low gain level, you can do nothing to improve this (except creating new MP3 files). So if the low gain level masks detoriation you'll hear at higher gain levels, then you'll have to live with that. Increasing the bitrate won't help.

Comment: Sure, I don't want to increase the bitrade to create quality that isn't there. I just planned to use the maximum possible bitrate to minimise the effect of loosing quality during  decompression and recompression

Comment: What would be the command to normalize with mp3gain?

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/39269/64451

Comment: Using a player that is aware of ReplayGain tags in the  files may also work.